# Linq Select into New Object Performance

Tags: performance, linq, object, select

I am new to Linq, using C#. I got a big surprise when I executed the following:

```
    var scores = objects.Select( i => new { object = i, 
        score1 = i.algorithm1(), 
        score2 = i.algorithm2(), 
        score3 = i.algorithm3() } );

    double avg2 = scores.Average( i => i.score2); // algorithm1() is called for every object
    double cutoff2 = avg2 + scores.Select( i => i.score2).StdDev(); // algorithm1() is called for every object

    double avg3 = scores.Average( i => i.score3); // algorithm1() is called for every object
    double cutoff3 = avg3 + scores.Select( i => i.score3).StdDev(); // algorithm1() is called for every object

    foreach( var s in scores.Where( i => i.score2 > cutoff2 | i.score3 > cutoff3 ).OrderBy( i => i.score1 )) // algorithm1() is called for every object
    {
        Debug.Log(String.Format ("{0} {1} {2} {3}\n", s.object, s.score1, s.score2/avg2, s.score3/avg3));
    }
```

The attributes in my new objects store the function calls rather than the values. Each time I tried to access an attribute, the original function is called. I assume this is a huge waste of time? How can I avoid this?

Comment: You need to materialize the query. So add a ToArray() after the first select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you've discovered that LINQ uses deferred execution. This is a normal part of LINQ, and very handy indeed for building up queries without actually executing anything until you need to - which in turn is great for pipelines of multiple operations over potentially *huge* data sources which can be streamed.

For more details about how LINQ to Objects works internally, you might want to read my [Edulinq blog series](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx) - it's basically a reimplementation of the whole of LINQ to Objects, one method at a time. Hopefully by the end of that you'll have a much clearer idea of what to expect.

If you want to *materialize* the query, you just need to call `ToList` or `ToArray` to build an in-memory copy of the results:

```
var scores = objects.Select( i => new { object = i, 
    score1 = i.algorithm1(), 
    score2 = i.algorithm2(), 
    score3 = i.algorithm3() } ).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! I just wasted half an hour implementing a private class instead of using ToList!!!